# Why does `mb_eregi_replace` return NULL when the string contains extended ASCII codes?

Tags: php, ascii, multibyte

Using PHP v7.1.5, why does the PHP function [`mb_eregi_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php) return NULL if the string contains extended ASCII code `A0` ("Non-breaking space" according to [www.ascii-code.com](http://www.ascii-code.com/))?

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $t = mb_eregi_replace('d', '', "do\xA0not");
php > echo $t;
php > if( $t === null ) { echo "is null"; } else { echo "replace worked"; }
is null


php > $t = mb_eregi_replace('d', '', "do not");
php > echo $t;
o not
php > if( $t === null ) { echo "is null"; } else { echo "replace worked"; }
replace worked
```

Comment: Reading [this article](http://iconoun.com/articles/collisions/) (specifically the "What to Do to Convert Extended ASCII to UTF-8" section) shows that passing the string to [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) before passing it to `mb_eregi_replace` solves the problem. Is there a better way? For simplicity, should all strings be UTF-8 encoded before being passed to `mb_eregi_replace`?

Comment: By default `mb_eregi_replace` uses [`mb_regex_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php) for the encoding of the string. `mb_regex_encoding` says the default is UTF-8 for PHP v7.1.5, so it seems something else is causing PHP to interpret the string's encoding as Extended ASCII and break `mb_eregi_replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this article](http://iconoun.com/articles/collisions/) (specifically the "What to Do to Convert Extended ASCII to UTF-8" section) shows that passing the string to [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) before passing it to `mb_eregi_replace` solves the problem.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $t = mb_eregi_replace('d', '', utf8_encode("do\xA0not"));
php > echo $t;
o not
```